# Adobe Premiere Pro CS4 - Looping a clip

Tags: premiere, cs4

I'm trying to get a clip to loop on my video for its entirety. (The clip is the water mark.)

I can't really copy paste it everywhere, it would take hours (the clip is 10 seconds, on an hour long vid.)

So is there some way to do it? To loop a video so it will play for the entirety of the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the watermark a video or a still image? If it's a still you can usually just increase its duration.

Otherwise, copying and pasting is the best way to go about it. Copy and paste it 10 times, then select the 10 clips, copy and paste that 10 times, then select the 100 clips, copy and paste that etc. until you get the desired duration.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a function do to so, and you pretty much confirmed that there is not.